# 'ViewModel' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I am not sure that I understand MVVM correctly.
This is what I did:

BaseViewModel

```cs
public class BaseViewModel : ObservableValidator
{
    public event NotifyWithValidationMessages? ValidationCompleted;
    
    public BaseViewModel() : base()
    {}
    
    public virtual ICommand ValidateCommand => new RelayCommand(() =>
    {
        ClearErrors();
    
        ValidateAllProperties();
    
        var validationMessages = this.GetErrors()
                                     .ToDictionary(k => k.MemberNames.First().ToLower(), v => v.ErrorMessage);
    
        ValidationCompleted?.Invoke(validationMessages);
    });
    
    [IndexerName("ErrorDictionary")]
    public ValidationStatus this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            var errors = this.GetErrors()
                             .ToDictionary(k => k.MemberNames.First(), v => v.ErrorMessage) ?? new Dictionary<string, string?>();
    
            var hasErrors = errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var error);
            return new ValidationStatus(hasErrors, error ?? string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

RegisterModel

```cs
public class RegisterModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name is required")]
    public string? Username { get; set; }
    
    [EmailAddress]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string? Password { get; set; }
    
    public RegisterModel() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

RegisterViewModel

```cs
public class RegisterViewModel : RegisterModel
{
    private readonly ISecurityClient securityClient;
    
    public RegisterViewModel(ISecurityClient securityClient) : base()
    {
        this.securityClient = securityClient;
    }
    
    public ICommand NavigateToLoginPageCommand => new RelayCommand(async() =>
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(PageRoutes.LoginPage, true)
    );
    
    public ICommand RegisterCommand => new RelayCommand(OnRegisterCommand);
    
    private async void OnRegisterCommand()
    {
        if (this?.HasErrors ?? true)
            return;
    
        var requestParam = this.ConvertTo<RegisterModel>();
    
        var success = await securityClient.RegisterAsync(requestParam);
    
        if (!success)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Register faild", "OK");
            return;
        }
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Registered successfully.\nYou can now login.", "OK");
    
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(PageRoutes.LoginPage, true);
    }
}
```

RegisterPage (code-behind)

```cs
public partial class RegisterPage : ContentPage
{
    public RegisterViewModel ViewModel => BindingContext as RegisterViewModel;
    
    public RegisterPage(RegisterViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        viewModel.ValidationCompleted += OnValidationHandler;
    }
    
    private void OnValidationHandler(Dictionary<string, string?> validationMessages)
    {
        if (validationMessages is null)
            return;
    
        lblValidationErrorUserName.Text = validationMessages.GetValueOrDefault("username");
        lblValidationErrorEmail.Text = validationMessages.GetValueOrDefault("email");
        lblValidationErrorPassword.Text = validationMessages.GetValueOrDefault("password");
    }
}
```

When I add the following line to the XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:RegisterViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

I get the the following error:
*'RegisterViewModel' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter.*

Whole XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MauiUI.Pages.RegisterPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiUI.ViewModels"
             Title="Register">
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:RegisterViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="25" Padding="20,0"
                             VerticalOptions="Center">
    
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="Welcome to Amazons of Vollyeball" FontSize="28" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
    
            <Image Source="volleyball.png"
                HeightRequest="250"
                WidthRequest="250"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Frame ZIndex="1" HasShadow="True" BorderColor="White"
                       HeightRequest="55" WidthRequest="55" CornerRadius="25"
                       Margin="0,0,-32,0">
                    <Image Source="user.png" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" />
                </Frame>
                <Frame HasShadow="True" Padding="0" BorderColor="White" HeightRequest="55" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Entry x:Name="username" Margin="35,0,20,0" VerticalOptions="Center" Placeholder="email"  Keyboard="Email"
                           Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           toolkit:SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior.NextElement="{x:Reference email}"
                           ReturnType="Next">
                        <Entry.Behaviors>
                            <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                                EventName="TextChanged"
                                Command="{Binding [Username].HasError}" />
                        </Entry.Behaviors>
                    </Entry>
                </Frame>
                <Label x:Name="lblValidationErrorUserName" Text="{Binding [Username].Error}" TextColor="Red" />
            </StackLayout>
    
    
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Frame ZIndex="1" HasShadow="True" BorderColor="White"
                       HeightRequest="55" WidthRequest="55" CornerRadius="25"
                       Margin="0,0,-32,0">
                    <Image Source="email.png" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" />
                </Frame>
                <Frame HasShadow="True" Padding="0" BorderColor="White" HeightRequest="55" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Entry x:Name="email" Margin="35,0,20,0" VerticalOptions="Center" Placeholder="email"  Keyboard="Email"
                           Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           toolkit:SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior.NextElement="{x:Reference password}"
                           ReturnType="Next">
                        <Entry.Behaviors>
                            <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                                EventName="TextChanged"
                                Command="{Binding [Email].HasError}" />
                        </Entry.Behaviors>
                    </Entry>
                </Frame>
                <Label x:Name="lblValidationErrorEmail" Text="{Binding [Email].Error}" TextColor="Red" />
            </StackLayout>
    
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Frame ZIndex="1" HasShadow="True" BorderColor="White" 
                       HeightRequest="55" WidthRequest="55" CornerRadius="25"
                       Margin="0,0,-32,0">
                    <Image Source="password.jpg" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"/>
                </Frame>
                <Frame HasShadow="True" Padding="0" BorderColor="White" HeightRequest="55" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Entry x:Name="password" Margin="35,0,20,0" VerticalOptions="Center" Placeholder="password" IsPassword="True"
                           Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <Entry.Behaviors>
                            <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                                EventName="TextChanged"
                                Command="{Binding [Password].HasError}" />
                        </Entry.Behaviors>
                    </Entry>
                </Frame>
                <Label x:Name="lblValidationErrorPassword" Text="{Binding [Password].Error}" TextColor="Red" />
            </StackLayout>
    
            <Button Text="Register" WidthRequest="120" CornerRadius="25" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Blue"
                    Command="{Binding RegisterCommand}" />
    
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="5" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Have an account?" TextColor="Gray"/>
                <Label>
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span Text="Login" TextColor="Blue">
                                <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding NavigateToLoginPageCommand}" />
                                </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Span>
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
    
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

I registered the page and the view model in DI container.

```cs
//viewModels
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RegisterViewModel>();

//pages
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RegisterPage>();
```

Any guidance is welcome.

Comment: The problem is that your ViewModel defines a constructor with parameters while you're not providing any arguments when instantiating the ViewModel. You cannot do that, you need to pass the required parameter to the constructor. Registering the ViewModel in the IoC container is not required, if you instantiate it manually in your View, BTW.

Comment: Don’t add those lines to XAML. Your constructor sets BindingContext, so xaml isn’t needed.

Comment: Do what @ToolmakerSteve told you, and ignore the other answers. Do not do manual construction. Register ISecurityClient, and move on.

Comment: @H.A.H. What's the added value of your comment here? There's exactly one answer so far and it's explaining what's wrong and how to solve it (exactly the same way that you're saying, too, by the way - not setting the BindingContext in the XAML and registering the `ISecurityClient`, if possible).

Comment: @ewerspej I am strictly against calling constructors. I think that my comment makes that perfectly clear. I do not agree with this part precisely: "you need to pass the required parameter to the constructor" , and this part too: ".AddSingleton<ISecurityClient>(new SecurityClient());". I want the OP to hear my point of view as well as others.

Comment: @H.A.H. That's fine, you don't need to be a fan of calling constructors, I'm also not advocating it. Your comment simply doesn't help with understanding the problem at hand. There's a ViewModel constructor which requires a parameter and not providing it causes the problem. There are several valid solutions to this, it's up to the OP to choose the one he deems appropriate, whether through DI or manually calling the constructor, at some point the object needs to be constructed and passed into the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

Your problem is that you're trying to instantiate a ViewModel without passing arguments to the constructor although your ViewModel only defines a constructor with a required parameter. You either need to define a parameterless constructor or provide arguments to the constructor.

Here is your constructor:

```cs
public class RegisterViewModel : RegisterModel
{
    private readonly ISecurityClient securityClient;

    public RegisterViewModel(ISecurityClient securityClient) : base()
    {
        this.securityClient = securityClient;
    }

    //...
}
```

You're trying to instantiate it without arguments here:

```xml
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:RegisterViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

This instantiation is unnecessary, because you're already setting the `BindingContext` in the code-behind using the ViewModel instance that is passed in via dependency injection:

```cs
public partial class RegisterPage : ContentPage
{
    public RegisterViewModel ViewModel => BindingContext as RegisterViewModel;

    public RegisterPage(RegisterViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = viewModel;
        viewModel.ValidationCompleted += OnValidationHandler;
    }

    //...
}
```

## Solution

You can safely remove the code that sets the `BindingContext` in the XAML:

```xml
<!-- remove this -->
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:RegisterViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

And make sure that the required argument somehow gets passed into the ViewModel's constructor.

Here are a few ways to do this:

```cs
var registerVm = new RegisterViewModel(securityClient);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RegisterViewModel>(registerVm);
```

You could also pass the `ISecurityClient` into the IoC container:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISecurityClient>(new SecurityClient());
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RegisterViewModel>();
```

Alternatively, depending on how the `ISecurityClient` implementation is defined, assuming it's something like "SecurityClient", you could also register it like this (avoiding any constructor calls altogether provided that the constructor of "SecurityClient" doesn't take any parameters):

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SecurityClient>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RegisterViewModel>();
```

This should automatically resolve the constructor with the required argument.

## Further notes

If you want Intellisense support for your ViewModel inside your XAML, you could add compiled bindings to your XAML like this (using the `x:DataType` attribute):

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MauiUI.Pages.RegisterPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiUI.ViewModels"        
             x:DataType="vm:RegisterViewModel"
             Title="Register">
```

or use design-time XAML.

Comment: IMPORTANT: If you add any `x:DataType` to your XAML, you will have to ALSO add the correct `x:DataType` to any nested `ItemTemplate`, e.g. in a `ListView` or `CollectionView`. Otherwise Maui will mistakenly (and stupidly) try to apply the outer `x:DataType`, resulting in errors.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I didn't include that in my answer, because it doesn't seem applicable in the OP's scenario.